# Android Volley put file AWS S3 Signed request

Tags: android, amazon-s3, android-volley, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to upload a file to AWS S3 in android with volley, using a signed request.

I tried to implement [this code](https://gist.github.com/anggadarkprince/a7c536da091f4b26bb4abf2f92926594), but I have an error 403 :

```
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
    <AWSAccessKeyId>xxx</AWSAccessKeyId>
    <StringToSign>PUT
      x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 <!-- Not wanted parameters -->
      expireTimeStamp
      /my-url
    </StringToSign>
    <SignatureProvided>xxx</SignatureProvided>
    <StringToSignBytes>xxx</StringToSignBytes>
    <RequestId>xxx</RequestId>
    <HostId>xxx</HostId>
</Error>
```

So, how to remove `x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` from the volley request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply :

```
@Override
public String getBodyContentType()
{
    return "";
}
```

Comment: I lost two days of my life to this problem... Thank you for the only solution that worked ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in headers:

#### Content-Type

and
In body

#### Binary data:

```
public static byte[] getBytes(Context context, Uri uri) {
    InputStream iStream = null;
    try {
        iStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] inputData = new byte[0];
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int len;
        while ((len = iStream != null ? iStream.read(buffer) : 0) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        inputData = byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return inputData;

}


@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
     return null; 
}
```